# Where is the option to create platform application in Amazon SNS dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am on this page [Register Your Mobile App with AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-register.html) at item 1 of the first subtopic with the heading "To register your mobile app with AWS". The instruction says:

> 1. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/home and choose **Create platform application**.

But when I click on that link, I don't see the option **Create platform application**. It only has the options **Create topic**, **Create subscription**, and **Publish message**.

[image]

Comment: i think the service is not available in ohio region change the region to N virginia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently some regions don't allow you to create a platform application. I was having this issue as well and I change the region to N. Virginia and it allowed me to create one.