# SNS Application option not appearing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I wish to setup an Android Application in Amazon Simple Notification Service as described here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-android-push-messaging-sns/

Step 3 says: **In the SNS dashboard, under Common actions, choose Create platform application.**

But in my SNS Console there is no option for Application on the left hand side.

Why is this?

[image]

Comment: which region do you select?

Comment: USEast (Ohio) - Does this matter?

Comment: same question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534989/where-is-the-option-to-create-platform-application-in-amazon-sns-dashboard  I can see some regions dont have platform application available. your question is duplicated. I checked some other regions and some of them have the option some not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the option to create platform application in Amazon SNS dashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534989/where-is-the-option-to-create-platform-application-in-amazon-sns-dashboard)

Answer (score 1):

Currently ***(i.e as of 15th Oct 2019)*** Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) doesn't support push notification feature in the following regions **:**

**us-east-2**

**eu-west-2**
**eu-west-3**

**eu-north-1**

**ca-central-1**

**ap-northeast-3**

You will need to create SNS platform applications' using any of the following supported regions **:**

**us-east-1, us-weast-1, us-west-2, ap-northeast-1, ap-northeast-2, ap-south-1, ap-southeast-1, ap-southeast-2, eu-central-1, eu-west-1 and sa-east-1**